# Widgets and Post/Page edit/new blank, console errors only, no server errors

Tags: javascript, block-editor, errors

My post edit, post create, page edit, page create are completely blank pages (no WordPress navigation bar, no top admin bar).  My widget page has the top admin bar and side navigation, but the rest of the page is blank white

Debug on showed no errors, PHP error reporting, same.  Server log is clear of any errors

Things I have tried...

- Disabled all plugins, still happens
- Activated default theme, still happens
- Uploaded all base WP files (not overwriting .htaccess or wp-config.php) in <kbd>/{root}</kbd>, <kbd>/wp-admin/</kbd> and <kbd>/wp-includes/</kbd> with a fresh version in case there was something corrupted in update, still happens

Console messages below (from widgets, page/post is similar):

> blocks.min.js?ver=7ed7fe32dad771c4e0af4f56539ff156:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^{0,3}|/: Nothing to repeat

> widgets.php:164 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'unstable__bootstrapServerSideBlockDefinitions')
> at widgets.php:164
> (anonymous) @ widgets.php:164

> index.js?ver=5.5.3:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerBlockType')
> at index.js?ver=5.5.3:1
> at index.js?ver=5.5.3:1
> (anonymous) @ index.js?ver=5.5.3:1
> (anonymous) @ index.js?ver=5.5.3:1

> block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__unstableGetBlockProps')
> at Module.tr0p (block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1)
> at n (block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1)
> at wp.blockEditor.//Lo (block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1)
> at block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1
> tr0p @ block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1
> n @ block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1
> wp.blockEditor.//Lo @ block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1
> (anonymous) @ block-editor.min.js?ver=fc8c27c6e95e7e0d59b4e344cb9ddfed:1

> block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'BlockIcon')
> at Module.K51g (block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:2)
> at o (block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:1)
> at wp.blockLibrary.1CF3 (block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:1)
> at block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:1
> K51g @ block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:2
> o @ block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:1
> wp.blockLibrary.1CF3 @ block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:1
> (anonymous) @ block-library.min.js?ver=69fc06eecf1aeb26e48b8a47ed38179b:1

> dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'registerBlockType')
> at Module.189 (dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1)
> at r (dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1)
> at dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1
> at dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1
> 189 @ dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1
> r @ dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1
> (anonymous) @ dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1
> (anonymous) @ dynamic-blocks-1780.js:1

> editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'store')
> at Module.PLxR (editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1)
> at n (editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1)
> at wp.editor.16Al (editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1)
> at editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1
> PLxR @ editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1
> n @ editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1
> wp.editor.16Al @ editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1
> (anonymous) @ editor.min.js?ver=208cadf8632b62c7ccdf2f2feb2398e2:1

> structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'RichText')
> at Module.207 (structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1)
> at n (structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1)
> at structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1
> at structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1
> 207 @ structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1
> n @ structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1
> (anonymous) @ structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1
> (anonymous) @ structured-data-blocks-1780.js:1

> edit-widgets.min.js?ver=b186cec01f1a7bb6ab91380888bf69f0:2 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__experimentalGetCoreBlocks')
> at Module.ht (edit-widgets.min.js?ver=b186cec01f1a7bb6ab91380888bf69f0:2)
> at HTMLDocument. (widgets.php:1988)
> ht @ edit-widgets.min.js?ver=b186cec01f1a7bb6ab91380888bf69f0:2
> (anonymous) @ widgets.php:1988

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar problem and I found the solution in this post. Please have a look at https://wordpress.org/support/topic/block-editor-unexpected-error/

Comment: Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen after a WordPress core update. Clear any caching (Cloudflare/Varnish/WP Rocket etc) and your browser cache, then try again.